# Converting Character to Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe in R which has date column as character. When I try to convert it into date with following code it gives me an error.

```
   No      First Landing Page Submission Date
   1
   2 
   3          31-07-2016 16:57
   4          31-07-2016 16:38
   5             1/8/2016 4:58
   6
   7          31-07-2016 15:40
   8
   9          31-07-2016 14:49
   10
   11         31-07-2016 14:41
   12         31-07-2016 13:51
```

Data is exactly in above format in csv file.

```
df$First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date <- as.Date(df$First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date)
```

It gives me following error.

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

When I use parsing function from lubridate package it gives me coversion of this form.

```
df$First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date <- parse_date_time(df$First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date, orders="dmy hms")

  No     First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date
   1              <NA>
   2              <NA> 
   3         2020-07-31 16:16:57
   4         2020-07-31 16:16:38
   5         2020-08-01 16:04:58
   6              <NA>
```

If you look at 3rd row original date is 31-07-2016 16:57 and when I parsed it became 2020-07-31 16:16:57. Can you please tell me the correct way to do it.

Comment: Can you create a column name that is short?  Regarding the `as.Date`, you should also specify the `format` i.e. `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M` i.e. `as.Date(df$First.Landing.Page.Submission.Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")`

Comment: @akrun Even if I specify format it converts the date as 2020-07-31 16:16:57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lubridate's `dmy_hms` function with the option `truncated=1`

```
lubridate::dmy_hms(df1$FirstLanding, truncated = 1)
```

This option is helpful when the data is not complete. In this particular case, the seconds are missing which would be required for a DMY-HMS format.